# Is there a way to share a html5 canvas image with facebook api?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I found some tutorials of how to convert canvas to blob and post it to user's feed. But the "publish_actions" permission was removed from the api in 2018 and the new Share Api seems to accept only urls. Is there a way to share my html5 canvas image with no image hosting?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that with the share dialog. It only takes the image from the og:image tag of the shared url. You can only do this for Pages, with the API.